# force a request variable to certain value?

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on a project that somebody else wrote, and he uses a request variable multiple times in a form.  Is there a way to force a request variable to a certain value

for example:

```
 if request("PorR") = "Purchase" then
            if request("LoanAmount") = "" then
                 request("LoanAmount") = "0"
            end if
```

If not, I have to re-do a lot of code replacement...  Bummer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just store that request parameter in another variable and then use that? You shouldn't have any trouble changing the value then.

Answer (score 2):

Btw using `Request("var")` is considered bad practise since it means you aren't explicitly stating where the variable is coming from and potentially opening yourself to exploits since you don't control which collection ASP retrieves the value from (and QueryString comes before Form in the search order!)

i.e. you should be using `Request.Form("var")` or `Request.QueryString("var")`

See the official Microsoft [documentation's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) remarks section, the pertinent section:

> If a variable with the same name exists in more than one collection,
>   the Request object returns the first instance that the object
>   encounters.
>
> It is strongly recommended that when referring to members of a
>   collection the full name be used. For example, rather than
>   `Request("AUTH_USER")` use `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")`. This
>   allows the server to locate the item more quickly.